# How can I edit the quicklists via GUI?

Tags: unity, gui, quicklists

I want to make quicklists on my own.

How do I do this from the GUI?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## For Ubuntu v11.04 Only

N.B. this does not work with later versions of Ubuntu.

## [Unity Launcher Editor](http://laudecioliveira.org/blog/?p=303)

[image]

To install run this in the terminal ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> )

```
sudo apt-get install bzr
bzr branch lp:unity-launcher-editor
```

> Then, to launch it, go to your home
> folder and you should find a folder
> called "unity-launcher-editor" -
> inside this folder you'll find another
> folder "unitylaunchereditor" where you
> must double click the file called
> "main.py".

[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/quicklist-editor-for-ubuntu-unity.html)

Comment: This application is currently broken

Comment: Maybe you should add at least a mark in your answer saying the status of this application. Last time I tried it it was broken.

Comment: Ironic that, in order to do something via GUI, one must use the command line to set up that environment ;).

Comment: Why even keep this answer around if it's out of date?

Comment: @JorgeCastro - it works... but only for Natty.  I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/141266/8973 has working solutions.

Answer (score 3):

QLE Unity Quicklist Editor version 2 is now available:
**ppa:vlijm/qle**, or **https://launchpad.net/jonb.homelauncher/+download**
[image: version 2.0]