# Apllications not starting from launcher

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher

Some applications, for example python resourceEditor from the pythoncard-tools package, run correctly if I start tham from Terminal.

However, when I add them to the launcher and try to open them clicking on the icon, the icon flashes for a while, but the app does not start.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: edit the .desktop file to correctly point to the file

Comment: Thank you :) but where is the .desktop file?

Comment: here you go http://askubuntu.com/questions/43659/how-can-i-edit-the-quicklists-via-gui

Comment: Hmm... the unity-launcher-editor doesn't work: I can add and edit applications in the GUI, but they never show in the unity panel launcher.  I've tried restarting the session after editing with the unity-launcher-editor but no luck.  I've also installed `dconf-tools` as suggested at: http://askubuntu.com/questions/35625/how-do-i-make-unity-remember-which-applications-are-in-the-launcher/ but no, it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that this application does not come with a .desktop file, without a .desktop file you should not be able to pin applications to the launcher (as unity can not launch them again).

Essentially its a bug that you can pin this application at all, you shouldn't get the option.

you can potentially create a .Desktop file for this application and put it in /home//.local/share/applications/resourceeditor.desktop but i wouldn't recommend it for future compatibility.