# How to add entries in quicklists

Tags: unity, launcher, quicklists

The Quicklists is an amazing feature of unity.

But sometimes some options which I might want are not available in the quicklist.

For the simplest example:

In the Nautilus quicklist,suppose I need a directory that I had added in the home folder.

Now how do i bring it as an entry in the quicklists?

How could I delete some options from it?

How could I add separators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit / add new quicklists usign Ubuntu Tweak, is very esay to use and every thing is using GUI.

To install Ubuntu Tweak:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Then you have to open ubuntu tweak and go to the option Admins > Quicklists Editor

Comment: Oh..!! I had seen it one when i installed it..!! :D just forgot..!! thanx a lot! ;)

Answer (score 4):

MyUnity provides this and is in the standard repos. Install it from the Software Center, or use the command:

```
sudo apt-get install myunity
```

The options are on the launcher tab, quicklist.