# Error when trying to create desktop icons

Tags: icons, desktop-icons

New user to Ubuntu 14.04, and having trouble trying to create desktop icons. When I drag and drop it tells me :

Error while copying.

There was an error getting information about “/”.

Unable to get past this, not sure of the commands to do it through terminal screen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a launcher on the desktop, run this command:

```
 gnome-desktop-item-edit /home/<username>/Desktop --create-new
```

this starts the GUI application for creating new launcher.

In the command field, enter the name of the application, such as `nautilus`, or select executable from `/usr/bin` or any other directory.

Comment: This worked after I installed the gnome utitity. Thanks. Is there not a way to do a drag and drop operation? Very new to linux sytems and have seen it done on videos. Does 14.04 not support this? I will make sure to keep this command handy...

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your desktop icons with [symbolic-link](https://askubuntu.com/tags/symbolic-link/info) in terminal by this command.

`ln -s target_path link_path` , where your desktop path will be something like this

`ln -s target_path ~/Desktop/icon_name`

Comment: Tried but got this error:

Comment: ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/home/david/desktop/application://brasero.desktop’: No such file or directory

Comment: And what are you copying? Or what you exactly run in terminal?

Comment: Anything... I am just trying to learn how to make a shortcut to application on the desktop. Nothing I am trying is working.

Comment: Can make folders, just not shortcuts to apps...

Comment: Because the path /home/david/desktop/application://brasero.desktop really doesnt exist, if you write any commands in terminal use "Tab" button to autocomplete. If autocomplete dont work then something is wrong.

Comment: Not sure what you are using the autocomplete command for? Does this then create the folder/file after the command is typed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are DnD'ing from a location you don't own like /usr/share/applications you can't as DnD is a move.
So just copy & paste