# Put icon on desktop

Tags: 14.04, launcher, gnome-panel

How do you add a program icon to the desktop in version 14.04?  I thought you could search for the program in the Dash, then  drag the icon to the desktop, but I can't get it to work. I can add it to the launcher, no problem. 
I un-pinned an icon from the launcher and it doesn't show up in the list of apps in the Dash unless I search for it. Is this normal? I want to put it on the Desktop, hence the above question.

Comment: have you already tried these answers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop

Comment: You may have to enable desktop icons through unity-tweak-tool or gnome-tweak-tool. Either one of these tweak tools should work with the unity desktop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An easy way to create a desktop shortcut?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/450266/an-easy-way-to-create-a-desktop-shortcut)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the program shortcuts (desktop files) are stored in `/usr/share/applications/` folder.  So, if you want to create a desktop shortcut to an application that is in the dash, open a terminal window and type in the following:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/nameofapp.desktop ~/Desktop/
```

then you need to make the shortcut executable to work.  Type in the following from a terminal window to make it executable:

```
chmod +x ~/Desktop/nameofapp.desktop
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

in File Manager, I navigated to /usr/share/applications and right-clicked each icon (one at a time) and selected "copy to" and then clicked "Desktop" then "Select"  ...voila!  not as technical an approach, but it worked.